# A more elegant way for this python decorator

Tags: python, python-decorators

Basically I want a decorator with an argument list that contains more than just a function to be able to be called from both the @- and regular forms. I've "designed" a quick workaround, but it's ugly and executes a function in @-form immediately, which is an undesired side-effect (that's due to return body_two() of course).

```
def status_display_with_comment(comment, closure = None):
    def body_one(function = None):
        def body_two():
            print(comment)
            #an ugly workaround to be able to run both the @- and regular forms
            if function != None:
                print("Entering", function.__name__)
                function()
                print("Exited", function.__name__)
            elif closure != None:
                print("Entering", closure.__name__)
                closure()
                print("Exited", closure.__name__)
        return body_two()
    return body_one

def a_function():
    print('a_function executes')

@status_display_with_comment(comment = 'some comment')
def a_function_with_comment():
   print('a_function_with_comment executes')

a_function_status_display_with_comment = status_display_with_comment(closure = a_function, comment = 'a comment')

a_function_status_display_with_comment()
```

Thanks in advance.

P.S.: I have to wrap my head around that whole closure thing. Which is fun considering it could be done recursively like in Scheme (a long time ago for me).

Comment: Be careful going too far with the Scheme analogies. You _can_ write anything recursively in Python, just as in Scheme… but Python doesn't have tail-call optimization, so you often don't want to. For a half-dozen levels of recursion, that's not a problem, but when you start thinking of recursive folding to map over a list of arbitrary length, you're probably doing it wrong.

Comment: @abarnert, so how do you deal with tree structures then? A list, contained within a list, which is in itself an embedded list and so on, the one of arbitrary depth? My solution for now: def tree_printer(a_tree):
 for item in a_tree:
  if type(item) is list or type(item) is tuple:
   tree_printer(item)
  else:
   print(item, end=' ')

Comment: In Scheme, if your trees are known to be not very deep, you can use naive recursion, but if they may be arbitrarily deep, you have to transform that into tail recursion. In Python, transforming to tail recursion doesn't help, so you instead have to transform into iterative code. (That's the most important difference, but not the only one. For example, Python has comprehensions, iterative map/filter/reduce, all the stuff in itertools, etc. to make it easier to write iterative code, so often, even when recursion would work, it's not the easiest way to do it.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want a function that returns a decorator:

```
def status_display_with_comment(comment):
    def decorator(function):
        def wrapper():
            print(comment)
            print("Entering", function.__name__)
            result = function()
            print("Exited", function.__name__)
            return result
        return wrapper

    return decorator


def a_function():
    print('a_function executes')



a_function_SD_WC = status_display_with_comment('a comment')(a_function)
a_function_SD_WC()
```

Also works:

```
@status_display_with_comment('a comment')
def a_function():
    print('a_function executes')


a_function()
```

---

The regular, direct decorator already returns a closure:

```
def a_normal_decorator(function):
    def wrapper():
        return function()
    return wrapper
```

`wrapper` here is a closure since it has to keep `function` around even after `a_normal_decorator` finished executing.

---

For reference, this is how an idiomatic decorator is usually written:

```
import functools

def decorator(function):
    @functools.wraps(function)
    def wrapper(*a, **kw):
        return function(*a, **kw)

    return wrapper
```

That is, it passes arguments to the wrapped function and doesn't throw away its return value.

`functools.wraps` copies from the function being wrapped to the wrapper function `__name__`, `__module__`, `__annotations__` and `__doc__`, the documentation string.

Comment: status_display_with_comment('a comment')(a_function) - wow, I didn't know it was possible to chain-call functions that way... I guess Python is a lot more like LISP than I imagined. So it's kind of a love-child of C and LISP. Thanks man, it's already past 2am here - gotta go to bed. Python is such an amazing language - I hadn't had this much fun programming in years!

Comment: `Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.` You can call anything, because why not? :) Really glad you like it!

Comment: It's not very lisp-like: My parentheses key isn't broken yet.  I'd say the only language I've used where the syntax limits you from chaining things properly would be PHP (I'm thinking of `$value = get_array_of_some_sort()[0]`).

Comment: @Steve Howard That may be, I never used it in C personally, so I wouldn't know. We were always pressed to be OO in the college I attended, functions were always treated as second-class citizens. I guess that's what C# and Java do best.

Comment: Is there a name for that type of syntax where you "call a call" like in `status_display_with_comment('a comment')(a_function)`? I would like to study it. Sorry for my unrelated question.

Comment: @AlexD.: There's [a famous blog post](http://norvig.com/python-lisp.html) where Peter Norvig calls Python "Lisp with syntax". But that's really overstated. Almost every language people use today that isn't derived from C or Basic (and even some that are) lets you construct functions on the fly, and pass them around as first-class values. (Of course that wasn't true when Norvig was writing; more people were still using Fortran than using things like Ruby or Scala…)

Comment: @ShashankGupta: There's no real name for it because it's nothing special. `status_display_with_comment('a comment')` is just an expression that happens to be a function call, and to evaluate to something else callable. You could just as easily write `x = status_display_with_comment('a comment')` and then later `x(a_function)`. The feature of functions that take or return functions has a name: "higher-order functions". But even that isn't very special; it's an obvious consequence of functions being first-class values unless you do something wrong in the language.

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't get it before. Your example with `x` helped explain it to me. It's just the return value of `status_display_with_comment` being called with the second parameter. The return value is a function. I get it now :) Neat syntax.

Comment: @abarnert yes, that makes sense if you consider functions to be first-class citizens. Just like with objects someObject.getInnerObject.setInnerObjectsObject(null). It's a shame the college I attended taught us more to memorize some stupid class attributes instead of focusing on really important (and not boring!) concepts such as this.

Comment: @AlexD.: If you'd gone to college earlier, they would have taught you all about higher-order functions, including how they map to lambda calculus expressions, as long as you ignore types, because really who cares about types; meanwhile, for OO they would have just said "objects are demonstrably equivalent to closures, except for some of that type stuff that nobody cares about, and syntactic sugar which we could always add but why bother". Or, half-way between those two eras, you would have learned how types are the key to everything, and objects and functions are both trivial. Or…

Comment: @abarnert I do care about both types in the C-struct sense and functions, but I don't much care for OO-classes. Sure, I will use classes written by others if I can't avoid it, but I'd rather not write a class myself. To me personally OO-programming is counter-productive first and foremost. The thing with Java for example is that it's too restrictive, whereas I want my freedom of expression and Python offers me exactly that, all decorated (pun intended) with an easily readable and elegant code.

Oh and by the way: "Lisp with syntax", isn't that Haskell?

Comment: @AlexD.: Anti-OO dogma is just as harmful as pervasive-OO dogma. Java is painful because it requires classes even when they're the wrong tool for the job (and because idiomatic Java takes that to ridiculous extremes beyond even what the language demands), but avoiding objects at all costs leads to things like C `strtok`, or at least convoluted closures for no reason. Use whichever tool is right for the job. The Python stdlib is a great guide—they use classes in some places, and not in others, and in most cases it's obvious why the alternative would be harder to read.

Comment: That's exactly why I said I'd personally avoid writing classes, but I'll use the classes written by others. I can just function (pun intended again) as a programmer better if I don't use OO at all. That's just me however, it's not that I'd be dogmatic about it: every programmer is free to use any tool (s)he wants. As for closures, I'll take them over classes any day. That's part of the reason I went on a new language hunt (after spending some time with C) and found Python.

Comment: You are returning too early. Replace `return function()` // `print("Exited", function.__name__)` with `ret = function()` // `print("Exited", function.__name__)` // `return ret`.

Comment: @AlexD.: There are many cases where a class is much easier to understand—and much less verbose—than a closure. Especially in Python. If you're avoiding useful tools in the language, and going out of your way to make your code harder to write and to read, you're probably not using the right language for what you want. Trying to use Python as Scheme with syntax is just as painful as trying to use it as Java with generic functions; using Python as Python is a lot more fun and productive.

Comment: @abarnert I never said I was using Python as Scheme. I'm just trying to use it procedurally. I don't really see much use for classes other than when you need an object that has an intrinsic behavior, like say a custom data structure such a self-ordering list or something like that. Another use would be when access modifiers and constraints are especially important. However, in my opinion here lies both the greatest strength and the greatest weakness of OOP - independence is a double-edged sword. Most of what I intend to program is better suited for a centralized control mechanism.